# Django autopopulate entire form with model data based of single choice field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make a modelform that populates all fields based on a single select field. Basically when the user selects a value from a dropdown it would then populate the rest of the fields based on data from a database.

**models.py**:

```
class Commands(models.Model):
    command_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    command_prefix = models.TextField()
    command = models.TextField()
    args = models.TextField()
    shell = models.TextField()
    role = models.ForeignKey('Roles', models.DO_NOTHING)
    os = models.ForeignKey('Operatingsystems', models.DO_NOTHING)
    job_type = models.ForeignKey('Jobtypes', models.DO_NOTHING)
    active = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**:

```
@verified_email_required
def jobs(request):
    return render(request, 'backend/jobs.html', {'form': CommandsForm()})
```

**forms.py**:

```
class CommandsForm(Form):
    name = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Commands.objects.filter(active=1).values('name'))
    os = CharField(required=True, disabled=True)
    command_prefix = CharField(required=True, disabled=True)
    target = CharField(required=True)
    command = CharField(required=True, disabled=True)
    args = CharField(required=True, disabled=True)
    shell = CharField(required=True, disabled=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^jobs/$', jobs, name='jobs'),
    url(r'^patchreport/$', patchreport, name='patchreport'),
    url(r'^prtbl/$', PatchReportTable.as_view(), name='patchreptbl')
]
```

**jobs.html**

```
{% extends "backend/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block title %}
    {{block.super}}Jobs
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form id="jobs_form" class="form-horizontal text-center" method="post" action="{% url 'jobs' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}

  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.name.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      {{ form.name|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.os.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Os</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      {{ form.os|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.command_prefix.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Command prefix</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      {{ form.command_prefix|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.target.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Target</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      {{ form.target|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.command.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Command</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      {{ form.command|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.args.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Args</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      {{ form.args|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.shell.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Shell</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      {{ form.shell|add_class:"form-control" }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jobs.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

To be honest, I am unsure of how to accomplish this with Django's ModelForms. Currently I took Michael Platt's advice and am auto-populating the fields with javascript on `change` event in a javascript file called `jobs.js`. I have to believe there is a way to accomplish the same thing by populating the entire form from the database directly, or via something like a RESTful api generated by TastyPie with an ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't too turned off by the concept of using javascript, you could use a .change() event for your particular select field.  So it would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_name").change(function() {
        // Find your different fields you want to populate and set the values here.
        // Example would be 
        if ($("#id_name").val() == "Some value") {
            $("#id_command_prefix").val("Whatever you want to populate with.")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The data is populated by a database, this would make it so I have to manually add that data myself right?

Comment: If you mean the default data that is expected in the fields when the user selects an option is populated by the database then yes you'd have to manually code those values into the javascript.  I think this documentation may be able to help too but I'm not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values  It looks like you can set some initial values in the form but essentially every time I've ever loaded a page then changed something I've had to use Javascript in some way, shape, or form.